# email not sending to given address

Tags: php, email

Hy!
I am trying to implement forgot password feature in my php code.
The code is properly working but email not is not sending to the address given in database against the provided id in field.
Help me in finding mistake !

```
<?php
    require_once './include/db_connection.php';
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
                    $sentmail = "";

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $query="select * from signup where username='$username'";
    $result   = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If the count is equal to one, we will send message other wise display an error message.
    if($count==1)
    {
            $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $pass  =  $rows['password'];//FETCHING PASS
        //echo "your pass is ::".($pass)."";
        $to = $rows['email'];
        //echo "your email is ::".$email;
        //Details for sending E-mail
        $from = "Coding Cyber";
        $url = "http://www.codingcyber.com/";
        $body  =  "Coding Cyber password recovery Script
        -----------------------------------------------
        Url : $url;
        email Details is : $to;
        Here is your password  : $pass;
        Sincerely,
        Coding Cyber";
        $from = "Coding Cyber";
        $subject = "CodingCyber Password recovered";
        $headers1 = "From: $from\n";
        $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-Mailer: Just My Server\r\n";
        $sentmail = mail ( $to, $subject, $body, $headers1 );
    } else {
    if ($_POST ['username'] != "") {
    echo "<span style='color: #ff0000'> Not found your email in our database</span>";
        }
        }
    //If the message is sent successfully, display sucess message otherwise display an error message.
    if($sentmail==1)
    {
        echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Your Password Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.</span>";
    }
        else
        {
        if($_POST['username']!="")
        echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Cannot send password to your e-mail address.Problem with sending mail...</span>";
    }
}
?>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="" method="post">

        <label> Enter your User ID : </label>

        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" />

        <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding email address in `$from`

Comment: @Apoorv
is it necessary to add any email address in $from?

Comment: @Apoorv
Anyhow, your trick did not work !

Comment: No adding email address is not necessary
And check you spam folder for the email.

Comment: @Apoorv
Not found in spam folder too

Comment: Then check your server setting
I am getting the email in my spam folder with your code

And are you getting count as one every time???

Comment: Oh wow - so many things about this. Firstly, I can send password reset mails to every single user in your system without knowing the username because of SQL injection. Secondly you should NOT store the password in cleartext as it's incredibly insecure. ALWAYS hash the passwords (using `password_hash()`) and verify with `password_verify`. Please read [the OWASP Forgot Password Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet). On the bright side I now know never to sign up for this site as you keep my password in cleartext, so thanks. See: http://plaintextoffenders.com

Comment: @h2ooooooo
Thanks buddy !.
I wanna go with some secure approach now